# Image not found or type unknown dompdf using laravel with Voyager

Tags: html, laravel, dompdf, voyager

I have to put images in my PDF, however the images cannot display, instead it display like `image not found or type unknown` There are two images that have to display:

1. from public directory `/default.png`
2. from Voyager settings `Voyager::image(setting('admitcard.signature'))`

Below are my code:

```
$pdf = PDF::setOptions(['isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true)->loadView('pdf', compact('data'));
return $pdf->download($data->name.'-admit-card.pdf');
```

If I didn't use `setOptions` then the public image is display but not Voyager Image.

Below are my html:

```
<img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/default.png" alt="default">
<img src="{{ Voyager::image(setting('admitcard.signature')) }}" width="70">
```

I've search but cannot debug, any help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance

Comment: Found that `isRemoteEnabled` is `true` by default..

Comment: FYI: both images are display in html, only cannot display in PDF

Answer (score 0):

For those who have problem like me I solved it like below:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf', compact('data'));
return $pdf->download($data->name.'-admit-card.pdf');
```

And in HTML:

```
<img src="default.png" alt="default">
<img src="storage/{{ setting('admitcard.signature') }}" width="70">
```